# I am trying to get all the folder inside publication but getting some error

Tags: core-service

I am trying to get all the folder inside publication. Here is the snapshot of the code I am using

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should use it like this:

```
RepositoryItemsFilterData repositoryItemsFilterData = new RepositoryItemsFilterData()
{
    BaseColumns = ListBaseColumns.Extended,
    ItemTypes = new[] { ItemType.Folder },
    Recursive = true,
    ShowNewItems = true
};
XElement filterResults = client.GetListXml(publicationId, repositoryItemsFilterData);
```

i used getlistxml() method but you can use async one. **The problem was the filter you used. It expects to work with OrganizationalItem, and publication is not an OrganizationalItem.**

[image]

Comment: Yeah Its working now. I've used RepositoryItemsFilterData fiter its working fine. Thanks

Comment: Note that both filters share a common base class: `ItemsFilterData`.  We wanted to make the distinction between Repository-level items filter and OrgItem-level items filter clear and thus we ended up with this yaw-breaking OrganizationalItemItemsFilter. :-)