# How to get Folders inside Publication using core serives

Tags: core-service

I am trying to get Folders just inside the publication not all the folders in the publication
Is there any way we can do it?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I am trying to get all the folder inside publication but getting some error](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/21918/i-am-trying-to-get-all-the-folder-inside-publication-but-getting-some-error)

Comment: Check my previous answer and remove recursive: true.

Comment: Might be important to mention that in the screenshot above there is only one folder: Building Blocks. The rest are different types of objects, if you're trying to get those too then you may want to look at their types and look up the logic to fetch them.

Comment: hheehehhe yeah :D

Comment: @Neil it's giving all the folders inside the publication I just want child folder or the Folder only one level down

Comment: @Sneh - that because of the Recursive = true. Use the RepositoryItemsFilterDatafilter if you're passing a publication Id as Marko suggested or OrganizationalItemItemsFilterData if your passing a folder itself. Recursive should be false (the default).

Answer (score 3):

As [Marko suggested](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/21918/i-am-trying-to-get-all-the-folder-inside-publication-but-getting-some-error) use the RepositoryItemsFilterDatafilter but dont set Recursive.

```
var client = // Get your client how ever you prefer
    
    var filter = new RepositoryItemsFilterData {
        ItemTypes = new[] { ItemType.Folder }
    };
    // Pass publication Id
    client.GetListXml("tcm:0-233-1", filter);
```